# Cauchy repeated integral formula for not continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

As at the title, I can't find the version of that theorem not assuming that f is continuous (example http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_formula_for_repeated_integration) while I think that the inductive proof for that formula will work for every Riemann integrable function $f$ since for that functions:

$$ \int_a^x \int_a^{\sigma_1}\left(\sigma_1-t\right)^{n-1} f(t)\,\mathrm{d}t\,\mathrm{d}\sigma_1 = \int_a^x \int_t^x\left(\sigma_1-t\right)^{n-1} f(t)\,\mathrm{d}\sigma_1\,\mathrm{d}t$$

works. Am i wrong ?

Comment: No, you are right. I think it could be difficult to justify changing the order of integration with the Riemann integral if $f$ is not (piecewise) continuous, but if you allow yourself to use the Lebesgue integral, it's straightforward.